Show that the set of all $x \in \{0, 1\}^\mathbb N$ with asymptotic density $1/2$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
My task is to show that the set $$A = \left\{x ∈ \{0, 1\}^\mathbb N : \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{|\{i : x_i = 1\} \cap [1,N]|}{N} = \frac12\right\}$$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
My first thought was that we need to find cylinders such that $A$ can be constructed in terms of countable intersections/unions of those cylinders. I'm struggling with finding such cylinders and I'm not sure if this is the right approach.
Edit: my understanding of $A$ is that it is the set of infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s with a proportion of 1's equal to $1/2$.

is in the Borel,,,,! which sigma algebra? what is $(1/N|{i : x_i = 1}|)$?

I'm assuming $A$ is the set of all $x \in {0,1}^\mathbb{N}$ for which the asymptotic density exists and is $1/2$.  I've edited based on this assumption, so if I'm incorrect, feel free to roll it back.

Red shoes, I think it is the borel sigma algebra on the {0,1}^naturals set. And the term in parenthesis is the size of the set of terms in a sequence which are 1 divided by N, aka the proportion of 1's in the sequence.
Brian, I hadn't heard of asymptotic density before now, but it sounds right, I reproduced my professor's syntax pretty close to exactly, but am fine with the change.

For $x\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ define $U(x):=\limsup_{n\to\infty}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. This is a Borel function of $x$. Indeed,
$$
\{x\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}: U(x)< b\} =\cup_{k=1}^\infty\cap_{n=k}^\infty\Big\{n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i<b\Big\},
$$
for each real $b$. Likewise, $L(x):=\liminf_{n\to\infty}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is Borel measurable. Hence, so is $A=\{x:U(x)=L(x)=1/2\}$.
